# Django Microservices - skip all user created tables for non-user services

Tags: django

I am using Django in a Microservice architecture. I already have a `userService` for authentication with JWT with an `apiGatewayService` that checks if token is valid before routing requests to other services. This means that I do not need all the standard tables that are created for a user (user tokens, sessions, email etc) in my other services when I run `python manage.py migrate`.

Is there a way to opt out of creating these unnecessary tables?
I have read some people just saying not to run migrations so as not to create these tables, but I obviously want to create other tables (say I have an ordersService, I want an orders table etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that functionality at all, then remove the relevant apps from INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Thank you! Could you also add to your answer maybe for this use case which ones I don't need just for completeness sake. I went through all of them and it seems I do not need `django.contrib.admin`, `django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.sessions`. Regards.

Comment: Nope, when I run `makemigrations` then django gives errors on almost all the apps the I left out, like `Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Comment: That error will only happen if you actually use those models somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if `rest_framework` uses them. That's the only thing I added after creating a new project 60 min ago...  Will try and remove them immediately after creating my next service/app. Also after reading up a bit, should I not remove some `MIDDLEWARE` as well maybe?